# Simple C++ calculation giving odd outputs

Tags: c++

I'm working on a C++ program to calculate a speeding ticket fine for different speeds.

"The speeding ticket fine policy in (City) is $50 plus $5 for each mph over the limit plus a penalty of $250 for any speed over 85 mph. Write a program that accepts a speed limit and a clocked speed and either prints a message indicating the speed was legal or prints the amount of the fine, if the speed is illegal.In the program, you also need to display whether the number of miles over the speed limit, and if he/she is driving over 85 mph."

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    double speedlimit,clockedspeed,speeddifference,fineunder85,fineover85;

    speeddifference = clockedspeed-speedlimit;
    fineunder85 = (speeddifference*5)+50;
    fineover85 = (speeddifference*5)+300;

    cout<<"Enter the speed limit: "<<endl;
    cin>>speedlimit;
    cout<<"Enter the clocked speed: "<<endl;
    cin>>clockedspeed;

    if ((clockedspeed > speedlimit) && (clockedspeed > 85))
    {
        cout<<"The clocked speed is:     Illegal"<<endl;
        cout<<"Miles over the speed limit: "<<setprecision(2)<<speeddifference<<endl;
        cout<<"Driving over 85 mph: Yes"<<endl;
        cout<<"The fine is: $"<<setprecision(2)<<fineover85<<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"The clocked speed is:     Illegal"<<endl;
        cout<<"Miles over the speed limit: "<<setprecision(2)<<speeddifference<<endl;
        cout<<"Driving over 85 mph: No"<<endl;
        cout<<"The fine is: $"<<setprecision(2)<<fineunder85<<endl;

    }
}
```

I'm getting weird outputs for (speeddifference) like "-7e-310" and the fine isn't adding the additional penalty ($5/mile over the limit) but is only outputting "$50" or "$300".

Just looking for help, I've searched everywhere and I've come up short.

ty all

Comment: Did you try debugging the code to see where it is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calculating the speed difference and fines before you even input the numbers! Remember that the program runs line by line (without functions, classes, etc. just procedural programming). Furthermore, you declare the variables without defining them with a set value which is why you are getting random values.

Move the:

```
speeddifference = clockedspeed-speedlimit;
fineunder85 = (speeddifference*5)+50;
fineover85 = (speeddifference*5)+300;
```

to after you receive input.

**Edit**:
There seems to be numerous other errors and I've tried my best effort to fix all of them. Here's a reworked version.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double fine = 0;

    double speed_limit;
    double clocked_speed;

    std::string over_85 = "no";

    std::cout << "Speed limit:\n";
    std::cin >> speed_limit;

    std::cout << "Clocked speed:\n";
    std::cin >> clocked_speed;

    double speed_difference = clocked_speed - speed_limit;

    fine += 50 + speed_difference * 5;

    if (clocked_speed > 85) {
        fine += 250;
        over_85 = "yes";
    }

    if (clocked_speed <= speed_limit) {
        std::cout << "\nLegal\n";
    }

    else {
        std::cout << "\nIllegal\n"
                << "Miles over: " << speed_difference << '\n'
                << "Over 85mph: " << over_85 << '\n'
                << "Fine: $" << fine << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Changes**:

- Set a variable `string over_85;` to remove need of complicated `if` statement.
- Remove need for two different fines and instead have one fine with an `if` statement to add the $250 fine if necessary.

Comment: This works for speeds under 85 but I'm still getting an odd output for over 85. I put the calculations before the first if/then statement. Is there something else im missing?

Comment: I'm working on it.

Comment: See my edit to my post.

Comment: @UltraGold Thanks a ton. I'm unfamiliar with some of the language used in your revised version but it's functioning perfectly. EDIT: It's making more sense now. I overlooked some things. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @AlexZimmerman Consider upvoting and marking the answer as accepted if it helped. :) It may be the `std::` that is confusing. You used `using namespace std;` which removes the need for that. If you're a beginner, you'll learn about namespaces later, so don't worry about them. If you want, you can add `using namespace std;` to near the start of the program and remove the `std::` where necessary.

Comment: @UltraGold I'm only a month into C++, so I'm very new :) Thanks again